# Certificate error on HTTPS web scraping with python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data on a https website. This is my code

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

headers={
  'Host':'icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es',
  'Cookie':'viewed_cookie_policy=yes',
  'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
  'Sec-Ch-Ua':'"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114"',
  'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile':'?0',
  'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform':'"Linux"',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
  'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site':'none',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
  'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document',
  'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
  'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'Connection':'close'
}

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('https://icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es/icpplus/index.html', headers=headers, cert='/home/kali/Documents/Jorge/administracionelectronica-gob-es-chain.pem')

r.html.render()
```

I have downloaded the three PEM (chain) certificates that the website loads through firefox and joined them in one file and looks like this (With a total of 9 certificates in the same file)

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGtzCCBZ+gAwIBAgIQC0CzDw53M/lN743NvBzAyDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBe
[...]
N9s6FHkEzLhRQXEK3r/q1H2MEt1DST7LyHy2jRaRwRE/fCYgOr3SiZy+4Q==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDrzCCApegAwIBAgIQCDvgVpBCRrGhdWrJWZHHSjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBh
[...]
CAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /icpplus/index.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(524297, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3921)')))

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='icp.administracionelectronica.gob.es', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /icpplus/index.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(524297, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3921)')))
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/174#issuecomment-464950428), you can pass `verify=False` as parameter when creating your `HTMLession` object.

Comment: @white still gettting the net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error. [Issue comment](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/174#issuecomment-614908345)